# Teradata sql two conditions(and) to check multiple rows to determine validity

Tags: sql, teradata, teradata-sql-assistant

Suppose I have a table with Apple names and the color in another coloumn.

```
Variety        Color
  Fuji          Red
  Fuji          Golden
  Granny Smith   Green
  Granny Smith   Red
  Gala           Red
  Gala           Golden
  Gala           Green
```

I want to know which apple varieties have both Red and Golden.So the answer that I am expecting is Fuji and Gala. So how do I write the query. ofcourse this query does not work.

```
Select variety from table where Color like all ('Golden%','Red%')
```

My table has many columns and a huge table similiar to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`INTERSECT`](https://www.info.teradata.com/HTMLPubs/DB_TTU_13_10/index.html#page/SQL_Reference/B035_1145_109A/ch06.08.50.html):

> **INTERSECT Operator**
>
> Returns only the rows that exist in the result of both queries.

```
SELECT variety
FROM tab
WHERE color = 'Red'
INTERSECT
SELECT variety
FROM tab
WHERE color = 'Golden'
```

Answer (score 1):

I would write this as:

```
Select variety
from table
where Color in ('Golden', 'Red')
group by variety
having count(distinct color) = 2;
```

Given your sample data, I see no reason to use `like` and wildcards.